# How to restore MySQL dump from host to Docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, containers, restore, dump

I'm sure this is a duplicated topic, but I simply cannot get it done: I like to restore my database dump to MySQL container in run time, without modifying the *docker-compose.yml* file.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:5.4.45-apache
RUN apt-get update
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysql mysqli
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  php_service:
    container_name: my_php
    # Use Dockerfile in this dir to build the image
    build: .
    # Stop containers always after exiting.
    restart: always
    ports:
      # 'localhost' does not works from the host, but the IP of docker itself
      # (192.168.99.100 for example - shown on the top of the console)
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    environment:
      # Pass variables
      - API_TOKEN=xxxx
    volumes:
      # The current directory will be mounted to '/var/www/html'
      # WORKS ONLY IN USER'S DIR ON WINDOWS (~/Downloads for example)
      - .:/var/www/html
  # See https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/ for additional information.
  # To open up console, run `docker exec -it my_mysql bash`.
  # To restore a dump `docker exec -i my_mysql /usr/bin/mysql -u root
  # --password=test_pass DATABASE < DUMP.sql` should work, but it never did.
  mysql_service:
    container_name: my_mysql
    # Use an existing image
    image: mysql:5.6
    restart: always
    ports:
      # Let it accessible for other apps (mysql on host, IDE, etc.)
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'test_pass' # TODO: Change this
      MYSQL_USER: 'test'
      MYSQL_PASS: 'pass'
    volumes:
      # Named volumes (my-datavolume) has to be listed in the "volumes"
      # section - I don't know how it works or what is it doing at all...
      # (-_-')
      - my-datavolume:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  my-datavolume:
```

Steps to reproduce:

- Start Docker Toolbox on Windows 7 host
- `docker-compose up`
- Open a new Docker Toolbox terminal
- `docker exec my_msql /usr/bin/mysql -u root --password=test_pass -e 'CREATE DATABASE testdb;'`
- `docker exec -i my_mysql /usr/bin/mysql -u root --password=test_pass testdb < dump_on_host.sql`
- `docker exec -it my_mysql /usr/bin/mysql -u root --password=test_pass testdb`
- `mysql> SHOW TABLES;`

The database is empty. It seems that it does nothing, because the terminal responds too quickly. I tried out the dump by installing MySQL on my host, it can be restored.

Comment: Do you get proper output for something like `docker exec -i my_mysql wc < dump_on_host.sql` ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - it says the input is empty (`0 0 0`).

Comment: Assuming the file is really there, maybe the pipe did not work? Try `cat dump_on_host.sql | docker exec ...`

Comment: Nope, tried it without success.

Comment: `cat dump_on_host.sql` in Docker Toolbox (aka: host) shows the whole file, so it's not empty.

Comment: Are you running this on the Docker host directly, or is there some VM setup in between (like you'd need for Mac OS or Windows)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155992/discussion-between-bimlas-and-thilo).

Comment: @Thilo, StackOverflow warned me to continue in chat, please come there.

Comment: `docker exec -i database_container mysql -u root -p database  --password=you_password < test.sql`

Answer (score 97):

Try below command works fine for me.

Run it from docker host machine.

**Backup**

```
docker exec CONTAINER /usr/bin/mysqldump -u root --password=root DATABASE > backup.sql
```

**Restore**

```
cat backup.sql | docker exec -i CONTAINER /usr/bin/mysql -u root --password=root DATABASE
```

Please let me know in case any issue.

Comment: See the comments for the opening message.

Comment: On restore, better to save password in a file
Something like `cat bkp.sql |  docker exec -i CONTAINER mysql -uroot -p\`cat /root/mariadb-root\``

Comment: For larger data sets keeping compressed is helpful too. I use. `zcat < backup.sql.gz | docker exec -i CONTAINER /usr/bin/mysql -u root --password='root' DATABASE`

Comment: I get the following message: `mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.`

Comment: Can also use `docker compose exec -T`

Answer (score 29):

The documentation on dockerhub worked for me: https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

**Backup**

```sh
docker exec some-mysql sh -c 'exec mysqldump --all-databases -u<user> -p<password> <database>' > /some/path/on/your/host/all-databases.sql
```

**Restore**

```sh
docker exec -i some-mysql sh -c 'exec mysql -u<user> -p<password> <database>' < /some/path/on/your/host/all-databases.sql
```

Comment: For me also helped this way: docker exec -i mysql -u<user> -p<password> <database> < /some/path/on/your/host/all-databases.sql.

Answer (score 4):

You are using a volume, that means that after you restore the dump, data will persist.

You are also exposing the database in port 3306, so a solution might be to connect to the database through a client. You can connect to mysql with a graphical client like [MySql Workbench](http://mysqlworkbench.org/) and restore the database from there.

Or if you have installed mysql in your command line

```
$ mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306 -u test -p testdb < dump_on_host.sql
```

Answer (score 3):

Per the latest instructions at https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql you can do this:

```
docker-compose exec -T mysql_service sh -c 'exec mysql -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" testdb' < dump_on_host.sql
```

This has the nice benefit of not putting the password into your command history.

Answer (score 1):

ONE DOCKER DB TO ANOTHER DOCKER DB

**Backup**

```
docker exec containerid mysqldump -u root --password=root portal-db > lower-portal-db.sql
```

**Restore**

```
cat lower-portal-db.sql | docker exec -i containerid mysql -u root --password=root portal-db
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command

```
sudo docker exec -i CONTAINER_ID sh -c 'exec mysql -u root -p[YourPassword] database_name' < /your/database/directory/database_name.sql;
```