# How do you correctly import an sql dump into a Wikibase instance?

Tags: docker, mediawiki, wikibase

I backed up my Mediawiki/Wikibase database with

```
docker exec wikibase-docker_mysql_1 mysqldump -u wikiuser -psqlpass my_wiki > backup.sql
```

and then I tried to reimport it with

```
docker exec wikibase-docker_mysql_1 mysql -u wikiuser -psqlpass my_wiki < backup.sql
```

but even after successfully running the `update.php`, the old entities and properties don't appear in my Wikibase app. Is there any other script I need to run?

I installed Wikibase with Docker following [this](https://github.com/wmde/wikibase-docker/blob/master/README-compose.md) instructions.

Comment: When you try to navigate to an entity what happens? Do you see your json data for entities in the `text` table etc of the database?

Comment: And is backup.sql actually a file in your container? If not you will need to mount it or copy it into the container!

Comment: The above command didn't work for me too (don't know the reason, it would be great if someone could throw some light on it). I tried using the command `cat backup.sql | docker exec -i wikibase-docker_mysql_1 mysql -u {username} --password={password} {dbname}` to restore the backup using backup.sql as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579381/how-to-restore-mysql-dump-from-host-to-docker-container and it worked for me.